# Prove $X=0$, if $\det(I+pX)=1$ and $(I+pX)^n=I$,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

> Let the matrix $X=(a_{ij})_{2\times 2},a_{ij}\in Z,$, and $p> 2,p\neq 4, p\in \mathbb{Z}$,
>
> $(1):$
>   such that

$\det(I+pX)=1$.

> $(2):$Suppose there exists positive integer $n$ such $(I+pX)^n=I$,
>
> Show that: $X=0$.

My try: let
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d\in Z$

since $X\in M_{2}(Z)$,and $\det(I+pX)=1$, 
then we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}
pa+1&pb\\
pc&pd+1
\end{vmatrix}=1
$$
then
$$(pa+1)(pd+1)-p^2bc=1$$
$$p^2ad+pa+pd+1=p^2bc+1 \Longrightarrow pad+a+d-pbc=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow p(ad-bc)+a+d=0$$
and since there exist $n$ such that

> $$(I+pX)^n=I$$
>   $$\Longrightarrow
> \begin{bmatrix}
> pa+1&pb\\
> pc&pd+1
> \end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&0\\
> 0&1\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   and Then I can't prove $a=b=c=d=0$.

maybe this problem use other methods?

Thank you  Salman post his solution,But this is wrong,because 
$$I + p\binom{n}{2}X + \ldots + p^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-1}X^{n-1} + p^n X^n = I.$$
we can't have this

Taking determinants of our equation, we get:

$$1 + \binom{n}{2}(a + d) + \ldots + \binom{n}{n-1}(a+d)^{n-1} + (a + d)^n = 1.$$

because 
$$det(A_{1}+A_{2}+\cdots+A_{n})\neq det(A_{1})+det(A_{2})+\cdots+det(A_{n})$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume he means just $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Hello,Yes,I have edit.Thank you

Comment: No, i think you are on to something here, the theory of generalized inverses. Suppose a matrix has a 0 eigenvalue. I will define the generalized inverse to be the smallest n such that A^n=0 (if it even exists). Verify this.

Comment: Something still seems wrong with the question.  What if we chose $X$ so that $I + 2X$ was a rotation by $45$ degrees?

Comment: I have a feeling $X$ has to satisfy some sort of integer property too, ie) $X \in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: This problem is my frend give me, X∈GL_2(R),p是奇质数,det(I+pX)=1,且存在n使得(I+pX)^n=I.求证，X=0.目前我用的线代方法，而且可以放宽到p是大于2的整数即可

Comment: That all came up in Chinese

Comment: maybe $X\in GL_{2}(R)$?

Comment: But as the first person said, $X = 0$ isn't a possibility, so instead of saying "Show that $X=0$", maybe "Show it to be impossible"

Comment: Gee, I thought we had been over this. If $X$ is invertible, then it can't be zero. There's nothing more to discuss about this.

Comment: I agree @PeterHalburt mean,maybe this is  the theory of generalized inverses?

Comment: Take $X=-I$, $p=2$.

Comment: And even if that were the question, let $X = -I$ and $p = 2$.

Comment: Or even $X = -\frac{1}{2} I$, $p=4$...

Comment: if $p>2$,and $X\in M_{2}(Z)$? then this problem is true?

Comment: We can keep changing the problem all we want until it becomes a problem but it seems a bit weird to do that.  Are you actually interested in the problem for any reason?

Comment: Now in china is middle of the night,I must go bed, and Tomorrow I ask my friend it,and Thank you everyone

Comment: Take $X = -\frac{1}{n}I$ and $p=2n$ for any $n \geq 1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom,Hello,I have edit. Thank you ,and Now this problem is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = I + pX$. Then $A$ is an integer matrix satisfying $A^n = I$, i.e. an integer matrix with finite order. This necessarily forces the minimal polynomial to be a product of distinct cyclotomic polynomials.

Given that $A$ is $2\times 2$, one can easily narrow the minimal polynomial down to one of the following:
$$\mu_A(x) = \begin{cases}\Phi_1(x) = x-1
\\ \Phi_2(x) = x+1
\\ \Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(x) = x^2 - 1
\\ \Phi_3(x) = x^2 + x + 1
\\ \Phi_4(x) = x^2 + 1
\\ \Phi_6(x) = x^2 - x + 1\end{cases}$$
The remaining is rather tedious, but straight forward.

1. The first case with $\mu_A = \Phi_1$ trivially forces $X=0$.
2. The second case with $\mu_A = \Phi_2$ gives
   $$A+I = 2I + pX = 0\implies 2I=-pX$$
   This requires $p \le 2$ which doesn't work out.
3. If we have $\mu_A = \Phi_1\Phi_2$ then the determinant is $-1$. No good.
4. If we have $\mu_A = \Phi_3$ then we get
   $$(I + pX)^2 + A + I = 2I + 2pX + p^2X^2 + A = 3A + p^2X^2=0$$
   This gives us
   $$3A = -p^2X^2 \implies 9 = p^4(\det X)^2$$
   This is impossible since $\det X$ is an integer and $p > 2$.
5. Continuing, we have $\mu_A = \Phi_4$. Then we have
   $$(I + pX)^2 + I = 2I + 2pX + p^2X^2 = 2A + p^2X^2 = 0$$
   Again taking determinants, we end up with $4 = p^4 (\det X)^2$. Again, this is impossible.
6. Finally, with $\mu_A = \Phi_6$ we have
   $$(I+pX)^2 - A + I = 2I + 2pX + p^2X^2 - A = A + p^2X^2=0$$
   which comes down to the determinant equation $1 = p^4(\det X)^2$. Again, impossible.

This shows that any matrix $A$ satisfying the hypotheses of the problem necessarily has minimal polynomial $x - 1$, i.e. $A = I$. It appears that the restriction $p\neq 4$ isn't necessary, although $p>2$ is necessary to prevent the case $p=2$ and $X = -I$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The eigenvalue of a matrix in the group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite order must be one of the following: $\pm 1$, $\pm i$, $\pm 1/2\pm\sqrt{3}/2 i$.

Comment: then? I hope you can post your solution,because this problem is not easy.